# Returning a literal by reference and inline

Tags: c++, inline, pass-by-reference

Supposedly, returning a literal *by reference* in C++ is bad since the literal goes out of scope then leaving the function:

```
const char &ToBoolean(bool val) const 
{ 
    return val ? (const char &)"1" : (const char &)"0"; 
}
```

, but when using `inline` I'm guessing this should be ok since the literal's scope is now in the calling function, or no? Example:

```
inline const char &ToBoolean(bool val) const 
{ 
    return val ? (const char &)"1" : (const char &)"0"; 
}
```

This is how I plan to use it:

```
void testToBoolean1()
{
     bool val = true;
     const char *valStr = ToBoolean(val);
     int result = strcmp("1", valStr);
     CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(0, result);
}
```

**Update.**

If static strings are ok, then how about this?

```
inline const char *ToBoolean(bool val) const { 
    char boolStr[6];
    if (val) strcpy(boolStr, "true");
    else strcpy(boolStr, "false");
    return &boolStr;
}
```

This compiles and runs fine using VC++ 2012.

Comment: `inline` has got nothing to do with string literals or scope...

Comment: `inline` also has little to do with a function actually being inlined by the compiler.

Comment: @jrok I understand now that the correct question should have been "Does inline expand the function variable scope".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*char const** is not the same as *char const&* (the former is a *pointer to char* the latter is a reference to a single *char*. Character string constants are allocated statically so it is safe to return pointers to them from functions.

```
inline char const* ToBoolean(bool val) const 
{ 
    return val ? "1" : "0"; 
}
```

Comment: If the method was `const char &ToFloat(float val)` and it returned a reference to function local `char floatStr[100]`, then would there still be a difference between `inline` and not using `inline`?

Comment: @IngeHenriksen That wouldn't compile. You can't return an array as a `const char&`.

Comment: @sftrabbit Check my update, that compiles and runs fine - should it?

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Two problems with it: 1) Your use of C-style casts is making this worse. `(const _UTF8*)&boolStr` will be a `reinterpret_cast` again. Although in this particular instance, you'll probably get away with it (I haven't fully confirmed that) 2) The `boolStr` array will be destroyed at the end of the function. If you return a pointer to it, the pointer will be left dangling.

Comment: @sftrabbit Will the pointer be left dangling even if the function is `inline`? Because, is not `inline` basically that the compiler moving the function code _inside_ the calling funtion - thus the function scope of `boolStr` will be inside the calling function. I will fix the casts now.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen `inline` *does not* effect the scope of variables or the lifetime of objects. You shouldn't even think about it as moving the function code, because the standard doesn't say that. The standard simply puts certain restrictions on `inline` functions that mean the compiler *could* move the code if it wanted to. However, `inline` will not affect the semantics of your program.

Comment: @sftrabbit That answers my question nicely. Thanks.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: `inline` only tells the compiler. 1. Try to substitute function call by function body *if possible* & 2. Relax rules w.r.t One definition rule(*ODR*). `#1` may or maynot be possible, `#2` is always done. `inline` gives you nothing more than that.

Comment: @AlokSave +1 for clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

String literals are different from local variables and they remain alive throughout the program lifetime.They have static duration lifetime. You can safely return pointer to a string literal.

**C++11 Standard §2.14.5.8:**

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).

**3.7.1 Static storage duration**
**Para 1:**

> ...The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the
>   program (3.6.2, 3.6.3)

---

Just to be clear, The type of the string literal "1" is `char (*)[2]`. This is because, type of "1" is char[2] and pointer to an array of 2 characters is declared as `char (*)[2]`, So If you need to take address of it. When returning a reference your implicit c-style cast devolves in to a `reinterpret_cast`, which essentially can cast pointer of any type to any other type irrespective of correctness. What it gets you in you case is an Undefined behavior. As mentioned above, What you can safely return is a pointer to a string literal. You need to modify your return type as:

```
char const* ToBoolean(bool val) const;
```

---

**Answer to Updated Q:**

Your updated solution merely copies a string literal to an array local to the function. The array does not exist beyond the scope of the function. So no it is not okay. It might seem to work but it invokes Undefined behavior. "true" and "false" themselves have static duration lifetime but you are not returning pointer to them, You are copying them to a local array and returning pointer to the local array.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Don't take this to mean that your code is okay though. It's definitely not. You're not returning a pointer to the string literal. You're casting it to a `const char&`.

Comment: Is even having a `const char *&` to a returned string literal okay also?

Answer (score 2):

`"1"` is a string literal of type "array of 2 `const` `char`". When you cast it with `(const char &)"1"`, this results in a `reinterpret_cast<const char&>("1")` which ends up giving you undefined behaviour.

Perhaps you're meaning to do:

```
inline const char &ToBoolean(bool val)
{ 
    return val ? '1' : '0'; 
}
```

Notice the single quotes. These are character literals, rather than string literals.

However, because the character literals are prvalues, the binding to the `const char&` results in a temporary object being made with the corresponding value. The reference is then bound to *that* temporary object. However, that temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the full expression (the `return` statement) and the reference will be left dangling.

And no, `inline` doesn't affect the scope of variables or the lifetime of objects. That would be silly because it's only a hint to the compiler about what to do. That would mean the compiler could choose to change the meaning of your code if it wanted to.

So instead, try returning a pointer to the string literal:

```
inline const char* ToBoolean(bool val)
{ 
    return val ? "1" : "0"; 
}
```

String literals have static storage duration, which means that they exist for the duration of the program. You can return a pointer to the first element in the string literal and be sure that the object it points to will always be valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
inline const char &ToBoolean(bool val) const 
{ 
    return val ? (const char &)"1" : (const char &)"0"; 
}
```

You return a string for a `char`? - also, if you really have to return a `const char *` then explicitly state it.::

```
inline const char *ToBoolean(bool val) const 
{ 
    return val ? "1" : "0"; 
}
```

Comment: I think you want to remove the casts.